# Micronaut 4 - java.net.SocketException: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline

Tags: kotlin, netty, micronaut

I started getting this error after updating Micronaut to version 4.2.1. It also happens at the same time as a 500 error from `/oauth/callback/provider` (didn't happen in micronaut 3). Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix or debug this?

Stack traces:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)

  at read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)

  at setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:255)

  at writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)

  at doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)

  at read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)

  at processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)

  at processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)

  at processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)

  at run(NioEventLoop.java:562)

  at run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)

  at run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)

  at run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)

  at run(Thread.java:840)
```